# Assigning variables from async method

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I am not able to call my async method... I am wanting to call that method so I can use the values in the variables inside of that method. **NOTE**: `ViewDetailsAsync` is coming from a web service.

This is what I have:

```
namespace TilesAndNotifications.Models
{
public class PrimaryTile
{
    public async void GetTileData()
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        string name= string.Empty;
        string description = string.Empty;
        string type= string.Empty;

        var res = await client.ViewDetailsAsync();

        name= res.NameView;
        description = res.DescriptionView;
        type= res.TypeView;
    }

    public string CurrentName { get; set; } = "John Doe";
    public string CurrentDescription { get; set; } = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.";
    public string CurrentType { get; set; } = "Employee";
}
}
```

**What I would like to accomplish**

```
public string CurrentName { get; set; } = GetTileData.name;
public string CurrentDescription { get; set; } = GetTileData.description
public string CurrentType { get; set; } = GetTileData.type;
```

But I am unsure as to bring that information from the async method... I know this may be rudimentary, but I can not seem to get it.

Comment: From the "public async void GetTileDate()"....

Comment: [Never do `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) unless you are writing a event handler.

Comment: You are getting everybody confused.  Your previous posting had an xml document.  The people at this posting don't know that.  Also your previous posting xml do not have the 3 properties CurrentName, CurrentDescription, and CurrentType.  Please post the correct XML that contains these three properties.

Comment: Because I have changed it, hence the new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set properties just fine from an `async` method:

```
public async Task GetTileDataAsync()
{
  ...
  var res = await client.ViewDetailsAsync();

  CurrentName = res.NameView;
  CurrentDescription = res.DescriptionView;
  CurrentType = res.TypeView;
}
```

Of course, the calling code will have to `await` the task returned from `GetTileDataAsync` before using those properties.

Comment: Ok, so I have assigned them to my variables. How can I call the GetTileDataAsyn() method? For it to actually execute?

Comment: @Code: `await obj.GetTileDataAsync();`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using property default values, and since class construction isn't asynchronous, you won't be able to do so on a constructor unless you implement a synchronous wait:

```
public PrimaryTile()
{
     var titleData = GetTitleData().Result;
}
```

Anyways, **this is a very very very bad idea because it may produce a *deadlock* under certain conditions if you don't implement your asynchronous/threaded code with a lot of care**.

Probably you need to re-think your architecture and work on a better solution.